# Which plugin gives me pretty html syntax in the editor/dashboard?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a plugin that gives me some on-the-fly syntax highlighting in the HTML editor of posts and pages. I swear I've seen it somewhere, but I can't find it, all the ones I find are for showing it nicely on the front-end of the post/page to users.

In case it's not clear, I Would like to have my HTML editor tab show me stuff like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdYvr.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/